Is the norm of first or second level of of signature a convex function?
I understand this is not a research level question but I really want to know, would anyone please help.
This question is related to the signatures that arises in rough path theory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_path
Is there any reference to understand if the norms of the different levels of signatures are convex function or not? is it possible to derive under what condition the norm (L1 or L2) of the first or second level of signature would be convex? As I understand L1 and L2 norm are convex by definition, but is that applicable to the first and second level of signature. The Gemini,large language model says no, so I am confused.

I would not trust anything any llm says…

@user479223 really, I had lot of confidence in llm. I need to be careful.  Thank you.

@Creator What do you mean by convexity? If you mean of the underlying path (eg. studying $\lambda X+(1-\lambda)Y$), then ,even in the smooth case, that doesn't seem possible for the second and higher-level where you have iterated integrals and thus cross-terms.

@ThomasKojar Thank you for your interest. Suppose I do hadamard product (a variable) of a given path  now the first level will be a vector 1xd and the second level will be dxd matrix. The norms of theese level with respect to the variable is convex or not?
